# CSS3 Only Slider with continuous rotation

Tags: html, css, slider

I have been working on a slider that I want to auto-rotate through 3 images every 4 seconds but I haven't be able to make the CSS3 Animation work.

When I enable the starting state of the images to opacity 0 they fade and never respond to my keyframes.

You can see my code on jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fchrisb/6wep1qL7/8/

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand");
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Just Another Hand', cursive;
  overflow-X: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 66%;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  /* box-shadow: 0 11px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24); */
}

.container input {
  display: none;
}

.container .slide_img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container div.slide_img {
  animation: move_slide2 12s infinite;
  //opacity: 0;
}

.container>div#one {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.container>div#two {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.container>div#three {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.container .slide_img a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.container .slide_img img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.container .slide_img .prev,
.container .slide_img .next {
  width: 5%;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  transition: .45s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .slide_img .next {
  right: 0;
}

.container .slide_img .prev {
  left: 0;
}

.container .slide_img .prev:hover,
.container .slide_img .next:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.8);
}

.container .slide_img .prev span,
.container .slide_img .next span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: solid 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container .slide_img .prev span {
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  right: 30%;
}

.container .slide_img .next span {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  left: 30%;
}

.container #nav_slide {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 12%;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
}

.container #nav_slide .dots {
  top: -5px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: .4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container #nav_slide #dot1:hover {
  background: #795548;
}

.container #nav_slide #dot2:hover {
  background: #F44336;
}

.container #nav_slide #dot3:hover {
  background: #2196F3;
}

#i1:checked~#one,
#i2:checked~#two,
#i3:checked~#three {
  z-index: 9;
  animation: scroll 1s ease-in-out;
}

#i1:checked~#nav_slide #dot1 {
  background: #795548;
}

#i2:checked~#nav_slide #dot2 {
  background: #F44336;
}

#i3:checked~#nav_slide #dot3 {
  background: #2196F3;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes move_slide2 {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 66%;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .container .slide_img .prev,
  .container .slide_img .next {
    width: 10%;
  }
  .container .slide_img .prev span,
  .container .slide_img .next span {
    border: solid 12px;
  }
  .container .slide_img .prev span {
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  }
  .container .slide_img .next span {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  }
  .container #nav_slide .dots {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked/>
  <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i3" name="images" />

  <div class="slide_img" id="one">

    <a href="https://marcomcentral.app.pti.com/Worth_Higgins_%26_Assoc.,_Inc./Access/catalog.aspx?uigroup_id=530928"><img src="https://worthhiggins.startlogic.com/wha/access/images/image_1c.jpg" style="border: 0;"></a>

    <label class="prev" for="i4"><span></span></label>
    <label class="next" for="i2"><span></span></label>

  </div>
  <div class="slide_img" id="two">

    <a href="https://marcomcentral.app.pti.com/Worth_Higgins_%26_Assoc.,_Inc./Access/catalog.aspx?uigroup_id=530928"><img src="https://worthhiggins.startlogic.com/wha/access/images/image_2c.jpg" style="border: 0;"></a>

    <label class="prev" for="i1"><span></span></label>
    <label class="next" for="i3"><span></span></label>

  </div>
  <div class="slide_img" id="three">
    <a href="https://marcomcentral.app.pti.com/Worth_Higgins_%26_Assoc.,_Inc./Access/catalog.aspx?uigroup_id=530928"><img src="https://worthhiggins.startlogic.com/wha/access/images/image_3c.jpg" style="border: 0;"></a>

    <label class="prev" for="i2"><span></span></label>
    <label class="next" for="i4"><span></span></label>
  </div>
  <div id="nav_slide">
    <label for="i1" class="dots" id="dot1"></label>
    <label for="i2" class="dots" id="dot2"></label>
    <label for="i3" class="dots" id="dot3"></label>
  </div>

</div>
```

The css for the main animation element can be found on css line 28
The Keyframe - move_slide can be found on the css on line 137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animations are cancelling each other out. You can set them on the same line and that should solve the problem. 
Here's how `animation: animationName1 2s infinite, animationName2 2s Infinite`
Basically you just put commas between the two animations.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are running two animations on the same element that try to manipulate the same property - both `move_slide2` and `scroll` are trying to change the opacity, each its own way. `scroll` takes precedence and so, `move_slide2` is ignored.

There are other issues with the `move_slide2` animation, but they should be resolved based on how you resolve the conflict mentioned above.